# Java-produced signature does not verify with openssl

Tags: java, openssl

I am probably missing something very simple and stupid - I'd greatly appreciate any and all hints.

What I am trying to achieve is to produce a signature as per [Apple's doc](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/storekit/skadnetwork/generating_the_signature_to_validate_storekit-rendered_ads)

1. "CLI-like" setup

Sign.java contents:

```
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.security.KeyFactory;
import java.security.PrivateKey;
import java.security.Signature;
import java.security.spec.PKCS8EncodedKeySpec;

public class Sign {
    public static final String SKAD_SIGNING_ALGORITHM = "SHA256withECDSA";

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        byte[] keyBytes = Files.readAllBytes(Path.of(args[0]));

        KeyFactory kf = KeyFactory.getInstance("EC");
        PKCS8EncodedKeySpec pkcs8EncodedKey = new PKCS8EncodedKeySpec(keyBytes);
        PrivateKey key = kf.generatePrivate(pkcs8EncodedKey);

        Signature ecdsa = Signature.getInstance(SKAD_SIGNING_ALGORITHM);
        ecdsa.initSign(key);
        ecdsa.update(System.in.readAllBytes());

        byte[] realSig = ecdsa.sign();
        System.out.write(realSig);
    }
}
```

Produce the signature w/ openssl:

```
$ cat $(test_doc) | java -cp src Sign <(openssl pkcs8 -in $(private_key) -inform PEM outform DER -nocrypt -topk8) >$(java_signature)
```

... and verify the sig:

```
$ openssl dgst -sha256 -verify $(public_key) -signature $(java_signature) $(test_doc)

$(test_doc) - being simple message to be signed\
$(private_key) - pkcs#8 private key\
$(public_key) - pkcs#8 public key
```

Works fine!

2. Java without CLI setup

When I try to produce a signature like this:

```
@Test
public void SimplestSkadSignTest()
            throws IOException, SignatureException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, InvalidKeySpecException,
            InvalidKeyException {
        String SKAD_SIGNING_ALGORITHM = "SHA256withECDSA";
        String MESSAGE = "hello world";

        byte[] keyBytes = SKAdHelper.class
                .getResourceAsStream("/private_key_in_der_format.der").readAllBytes();

        KeyFactory kf = KeyFactory.getInstance("EC");
        PKCS8EncodedKeySpec pkcs8EncodedKey = new PKCS8EncodedKeySpec(keyBytes);
        PrivateKey key = kf.generatePrivate(pkcs8EncodedKey);

        Signature ecdsa = Signature.getInstance(SKAD_SIGNING_ALGORITHM);
        ecdsa.initSign(key);
        ecdsa.update(MESSAGE.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));

        byte[] realSig = ecdsa.sign();

        System.out.print(Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(realSig));
        
        ByteSink byteSink = MoreFiles.asByteSink(Path.of("/dump/anywhere/sig.bin"));
        byteSink.write(realSig);
    }
```

OpenSSL won't validate the produced sig.bin

```
$ openssl dgst -sha256 -verify $(public_key) -signature sig.bin $(test_doc)
Verification Failure
```

Both ways seem the same to me - what am I missing here folks?

Comment: @GhostCat thanks for your response! Probably could have mentioned that - I'm using java 18. There is actually a write(byte[] buf) method, have a look at: https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/18/docs/api/java.base/java/io/PrintStream.html

Comment: (1) you can't actually be doing `$(test_doc)` etc; that's not valid syntax in any shell ever (2) do `od -c test_doc` (or whatever the file really is) and make sure it contains exactly the characters h-e-l-l-o-space-w-o-r-l-d and NOTHING ELSE (3) PKCS8 is a standard for privatekeys only, there is no such thing as a PKCS8 publickey (although OpenSSH got this wrong and makes people think there is)

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 Thanks for the response! Ack'ing the public_key not really being a PKCS#8, TIL, thanks!  Reg. variables passed in shell - those should be understood as a variable, supplied in a way you'd like - ie Makefile or bash script or even env variable. I'll retry if the input file did not include any NUL chars or similar sillyness - thanks for the idea!

Comment: ^ as far as I can tell - the message to be signed is the same for both cases. No specia/weird chars as far as I can tell

Answer (score 1):

Tldr: both work. Problem was between my chair and the keyboard :-)

@dave_thompson_085 was on point, to be precise:

1. I've been creating cleartext message "by hand", in VIM. Byte-structure looks like this:

```
$ hexdump -C message.txt 
00000000  68 65 6c 6c 6f 20 77 6f  72 6c 64 0a              |hello world.|
0000000c
```

2. In java, there is a simple String w/ seemingly identical contents:

```
String MESSAGE = "hello world";
```

... but it is not. Dumped from java to file:

```
ByteSink byteSink = MoreFiles.asByteSink(Path.of("/cleartext_message.txt"));
byteSink.write(MESSAGE.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
```

internally looks like this:

```
$ hexdump -C message_java.txt 
00000000  68 65 6c 6c 6f 20 77 6f  72 6c 64                 |hello world|
0000000b
```